# java keywords in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, oop, keyword

according to this page
http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm
javascript has some keywords which are from java, reserved. I also notice that with the highlighting in my editor. Is this to be future proof? Are they planning to implement some more OOP style operators into javascript?

I would love to se interfaces, abstract classes and things like that coming to js, but does the reservation of these words indicate anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), §7.6.1.2 (Future Reserved Words):

[image: ecmascipt section screenshot]

And, from §2 (Conformance):

> A conforming implementation of ECMAScript is permitted to support program and regular expression syntax not described in this specification. In particular, a  conforming implementation of ECMAScript is permitted to support program syntax that makes use of the "future reserved words" listed in 7.6.1.2 of this specification.

Answer (score 3):

The words are reserved only to offer the original author ([Brendan Eich](http://brendaneich.com/)) a starting point on which to build keywords.

> In addition, JavaScript was designed
> with Java's syntax and standard
> library in mind. In particular, all
> Java keywords were reserved in
> original JavaScript, JavaScript's
> standard library follows Java's naming
> conventions, and JavaScript's Math and
> Date objects are [based on classes from
> Java 1.0](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roadmap/archives/2008/04/popularity.html).
>
> "JS had to “look like Java” only less so, be Java’s dumb kid brother or boy-hostage sidekick. Plus, I had to be done in ten days or something worse than JS would have happened" — [Brendan Eich](http://simonwillison.net/2010/Oct/16/jwz/)

There are currently no plans to integrate specific Java features into Javascript. The [current roadmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#Future_development) suggests these features:

- Classes
- A module system
- Optional type annotations and static typing, probably using a structural type system
- Generators and iterators
- Destructuring assignment
- Algebraic data types

Comment: "I had to be done in ten days or something worse than JS would have happened" - that's the best explanation of JavaScript's design principles that I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't guarantee anything, they were originally reserved "just in case" and have stuck in the language since then. They may or may not get used but most will not be used in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

@Andy and @OriginalSyn already answered your question and I just wanted to answer to this:

> I would love to se interfaces, abstract classes and things like that coming to js, but does the reservation of these words indicate anything?

It's very unlikely that these constructions have ever appear in JavaScript. JS follows [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_based) OOP model which doesn't use things like classes. This model has some advantages over classical, class-based model and you'll have to love it or stop using JS as there is no real alternative for this language. ;)

Comment: I like the prototype-based model, but I think the idea of interfaces would be possible to implement. In this case not for classes, but on a per-object basis.